# Batch rename files, create subfolders and move files by pattern

Tags: bash, mv

I have 500000 files in a folder and want to move them to subfolders. These subfolders should be created automatically.

The pattern is `{prefix}-{date}T{time}-{suffix}`.

The folder structure should look like `{date}/{time}/{suffix}`.

I have managed to remove the prefix with a bash script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for f in prefix-* ; do
        mv "$f" "${f/prefix-}"
    done
```

Comment: Ok. And what have you done this far?

Comment: Sorry, i added some code

Comment: Now add directory creation and move files directly to it.

Comment: But how can i get the folder names {date}?

Comment: Use `sed` (better `awk`) to pick each component: `date="$(awk -F'-|T' '{print $1}' <<< "$f" )"` (time and suffix are $2 and $3, respectively). The idea is to pass the string (filename) to `awk`, set `T` or `-` as separators (`-F` option) and then pick the selected field. With this you can create the dirs.

Comment: Can you provide an actual filename as an example? add 3 so the pattern is clear.

Comment: cut is a nice option too, as well the bash string striping

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the files never have dashes `-` or uppercase `T` in the names, you can build the following bash loop:

```
for f in *
do
   date=$(tmp=${f#*-};echo ${tmp%T*})
   time=$(tmp=${f#*T};echo ${tmp%-*})
   suffix=${f##*-}
   mkdir -p ${date}/${time}/${suffix}
   mv $f ${date}/${time}/${suffix}/
done
```

This is basic bash parameter expansion syntax, as per the man page:

> ```
>    ${parameter#word}
>    ${parameter##word}
>           Remove matching prefix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pat‐
>           tern matches the beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of param‐
>           eter with the shortest matching pattern (the ``#'' case) or the longest matching pattern (the  ``##''  case)  deleted.
>           If  parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expan‐
>           sion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern removal  operation
>           is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
>
>    ${parameter%word}
>    ${parameter%%word}
>           Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pat‐
>           tern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is  the  expanded
>           value  of  parameter  with  the shortest matching pattern (the ``%'' case) or the longest matching pattern (the ``%%''
>           case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn,
>           and  the  expansion  is  the  resultant  list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern
>           removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
> ```

I have used a temporary variable as placeholder, since bash won't allow for direct nesting of the expansion op.

`date=$(tmp=${f#*-};echo ${tmp%T*})`
`$f` is the current file name
`tmp={f#*-}` : remove everything up to and including the FIRST `-`
At this point tmp holds `{date}T{time}-{suffix}`
`${tmp%T*}` : remove everything after `T` (inclusive)