# Move files to subfolders based on part of their filename

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, directory, mv

I have files with filenames such as:

> text_2_2022-11-22_K03_10k_66_P578_B06_2999dl_text_693_coff_442.jpg
> text_2_2022-11-22_K03_10k_66_P578_B06_2999dl_text_693_coff_432.jpg
> text_2_2022-11-22_K05_10k_66_P578_B06_2999dl_text_693_coff_175.jpg
> text_2_2022-11-22_K05_10k_66_P578_B06_2999dl_text_693_coff_832.jpg
> text_2_2022-11-22_K08_10k_66_P578_B06_2999dl_text_693_coff_322.jpg
> text_2_2022-11-22_K08_10k_66_P578_B06_2999dl_text_693_coff_975.jpg

I want to create subfolders like:

```
K03_10k_66_P578_B06
K05_10k_66_P578_B06
K08_10k_66_P578_B06
```

and then move the files to the correct subfolder.

Other [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480803/can-bash-make-folders-based-on-a-filename-and-then-move-files-into-the-folders?noredirect=1&lq=1) use parameter expansion but I could not figure out to do this given the more complex names. Therefore I wrote a grep/regex command that matches the needed part of the filename but could not implement it in a loop:

```
grep '[A-Z][0-9]*_[0-9]*[a-z]_[0-9]*_[A-Z][0-9]*_[A-Z][0-9]*'
```

I have found similar answers ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480803/can-bash-make-folders-based-on-a-filename-and-then-move-files-into-the-folders?noredirect=1&lq=1) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350525/group-files-in-folders-by-name?noredirect=1&lq=1) [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325139/batch-rename-files-create-subfolders-and-move-files-by-pattern?rq=1) [4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350525/group-files-in-folders-by-name)) to my question but my filenames are more complex than in those questions.

Comment: If the filenames are so complex that there's no consistent pattern to reference then this isn't possible. `grep` isn't for operating via the names of files. It's for printing data from the contents of files based on regular expressions.

Comment: The filenames are complex but consistent, especially the bold part I mentioned. I want to create groups/folders based on the different bold parts: K03..., K04... etc.

Comment: Then you'll need to provide more filenames so that there's a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Do these filenames all consistently have 13 fields, each separated by an underscore character, before the `.jpg` suffix?  And you want to use the 4th through the 8th field to construct a subfolder name, create that subfolder, and move the file into that subfolder?

Comment: I have edited the question to be clearer.
@SottoVoce yes that is correct. The fields are consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in bash using parameter expansion, splitting filename into parts, re-joining a slice of the parts into the subfolder name:

```
# get list of .jpg files to work on
shopt -s nullglob
file_list=( *.jpg )

# quick exit if there are no files
[[ ${#file_list[@]} -lt 1 ]] && {
  echo 'No *.jpg files found' >&2
  exit 1
}

# handle each file in the list
for orig_fname in "${file_list[@]}"
do
  # get filename without .xyz suffix
  fname="${orig_fname%.*}"

  # split file name into parts on underscores
  IFS=_ fname_parts=( $fname )

  # join parts 3,4,5,6,7 into the subfolder name
  # note: includes trailing _ in name
  printf -v subfolder '%s_' "${fname_parts[@]:3:5}"
  subfolder="${subfolder%_}"  # strip trailing _ from name

  # create subfolder if needed
  mkdir -v -p "$subfolder"

  # move file to its subfolder
  mv -v "$orig_fname" "$subfolder"
done
```

Remove the `-v` from the `mkdir` and `mv` commands if you don't want their info to scroll on your screen.